# How to optimize my code for better performance and no lag in realtime

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, image-processing, pyqt5

I have a app with pyqt5 and receive data from `udp`, pack them and show.

I use threading(python built-in thread) for my app(one thread for `dl_data`, one thread for `save_log` and one thread for `ui`) but in real time I have a lots of lag in showing final image.

Part of my code for pack data is:

```
self.data_log =  [[0 for i in range(1000)] for j in range(1600)]
def unpack(self,pack):
        tmp = bytearray()
        for i in range(3):
            tmp.extend(pack[i])
        
        return np.asarray([newdiv(struct.unpack('<H',tmp[x+1:x+3])[0],256) for x in range(0,(self.NP) * 4,4)])

def merge(self,data):
        data = self.unpack(data)
        data = np.roll(data,200,0)
        self.data_log.extend([data])

def dl_data(self):
    while 1:
        for i in range(self.NPBN * 3):
            tmp = self.recv(self.bytes)
            self.merge(tmp)
def process_feed(self):
    while True:
        data = self.tcpsocket.recv(1024)
        if b'pressed' in data :
            if not self.get_data.is_alive():
                self.get_data.start()
def show(self):
   .....
if self.Mode == 'run':
    pressed= threading.Thread(target=self.process_feed)
    pressed.start()
    get_data = threading.Thread(target=self.dl_data)
```

newdiv function is "Making division in Python faster" [link](https://fredrikj.net/blog/2008/07/making-division-in-python-faster/)

Comment: are you using the threads from the `threading` module? or are you using `QThread`?

Comment: Sorry but your question is too vague and you didn't provide the *correct* details needed to understand where the problem could be. For instance, in what thread as the functions above run? And how is the thread implemented Please provide a valid [mre].

Comment: using threading.

Comment: except this part of code i have a four Qthread for my camera thats shows in ui and a python thread for listening when data arive and then dl_data called.

Comment: Consider using np.frombuffer and view. It may be faster. Alternatively, using Cython can help a bit. Moreover, why not using views instead of `np.roll`? It may consume more memory but it is faster.

Comment: The `newdiv` function you found is only faster for numbers with thousands of digits. But you're dealing with 16-bit unsigned integers which only have a maximum of 5 digits (in base 10). Also integer division by 256 is a special case, where basically the least significant byte is dropped. So you might as well pick only the remaining byte, e.g. `struct.unpack('B',tmp[x+2])[0]`, without doing any division.

Comment: @md.119 As said, your code is missing too many aspects to even *understand* how it works (and if we don't understand it, we cannot help you). So, if you want help, you **must** provide a valid MRE. Please, don't rush it, take your time, ensure that the code is *both* minimal *and* reproducible (we must be able to understand it *completely* by reading, or possibly copy, paste and run it without any essential modification), then [edit] your post by including it while ensuring that it's [properly formatted](/meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) by checking its syntax/indentation in the post preview.

Comment: If you're looking for good real-time performance, I suggest rewriting the program in C++ rather than Python.  Python's interpreted nature means that performance will necessarily be about 10% of what you'd get using fully-compiled code, and furthermore Python's GIL means that multiple python threads won't run simultaneously, which limits the amount of performance you can obtain via multithreading.

Comment: @user7138814
i test this but my i get error 'a bytes-like object is required, not 'int''

Comment: @md.119 Maybe with slicing it will be the correct type, ie `tmp[x+2:x+3]`. But it would be better to do something with numpy instead of the list comprehension + struckt.unpack anyway...